# How to use make Keras use multiple cores CPU in MacBook Pro M1

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I wanna ask if anyone is using their MacBook Pro M1 to build Keras NN model. It would be great if anyone can tell me how I can leverage all the cores of the CPU for training the model. I did some research but seem not able to get myself an answer, and Keras is using single core of the CPU for training so far.

Thanks alot!